# Searching with Codeigniter using the url to include disallowed URI characters

Tags: codeigniter, url, search, uri, encode

I want to implement a search in codeigniter using the search term in the url string but am having trouble allowing disallowed uri characters (' is the main problem)

e.g. www.example.com/search/find/search_term/collector's edition/category/stackoverflow

basically find 'collector's edition' in category 'stackoverflow'

This throws the URI exception error - even if I encode it with javascript codeigniter unencodes it. Obviously I don't want to go and allow all characters.

I also want to be able to decode my data when it is returned so I can display the search term in the input box also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query string rather than fight against CI's suggested allowed URI characters:

> `example.com/search/?search_term=collector's+edition&category=stackoverflow`

Just make sure you have query strings (`$_GET`) enabled:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE; // This enables $_GET data

// The name of this item is misleading, it's not what you might think 
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE; // <-- Ignore this, make sure it's FALSE
```

And to grab the search term:

```
$query = $this->input->get('search_term'); // No need to decode
```

Comment: thanks I'll have a look at sending it via the get example you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You need to add “=” to your allowed_uri_chars. You’ll find that string in your config/config.php file.

It could also be the . (dot) in there. Try adding a dot instead. You need to be a little bit brave 
and experiment to figure out what works.

Try `$config[‘permitted_uri_chars’] = ‘a-z 0-9~%.:?=_\-’;`

Comment: not sure where you see the = or .(dot) in my example : i'm looking for a solution without modifying the permitted_uri_chars

Comment: dude seriously I don't know what you are on about or what you are even looking at - thanks for the try but never worry i've the basics covered and have been given a solution to try